# error BC32210: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I have an app that I'm trying to deploy to Azure using the Development Center. The app works great locally but when I check in my code and Azure starts the deployment process, it fails with the following message in reference to System.Xml.ReaderWriter.4.3.1:

> error BC32210: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported

The message is confusing because my packages.config only references the assembly once and the app builds fine locally.

**How do I correct this problem?**

Here's the full log entry:

> Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
>   Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
>   MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64'.
>   Restoring NuGet package System.Xml.ReaderWriter.4.3.1.
>     GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.xml.readerwriter/4.3.1/system.xml.readerwriter.4.3.1.nupkg
>     OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.xml.readerwriter/4.3.1/system.xml.readerwriter.4.3.1.nupkg 300ms
>   Installing System.Xml.ReaderWriter 4.3.1.
>   Adding package 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter.4.3.1' to folder 'D:\home\site\repository\packages'
>   Added package 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter.4.3.1' to folder 'D:\home\site\repository\packages'
>
> NuGet Config files used:
>       C:\DWASFiles\Sites#1asdffdsa__fb6e\AppData\NuGet\NuGet.Config
>
> Feeds used:
>       D:\home.nuget\
>       https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
>
> Installed:
>       1 package(s) to packages.config projects
>   vbc : error BC32210: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'D:\home\site\repository\packages\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.4.3.1\lib\net46\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll' and 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references. [D:\home\site\repository\DiocesanClaims\DiocesanClaims.vbproj]
>   Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\DiocesanClaims\DiocesanClaims.vbproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="D:\local\Temp\8d70fa465288676";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\repository.\"
>   An error has occurred during web site deployment.
>   \r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\82.10503.3890\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the issue was or why it was a problem but luckily, I didn't need the assembly in question. I uninstalled it from the list of Nuget packages and I was able to deploy fine after that.